# Get "Add rating" on a custom form. (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, review, ratings

I have created a customized popup, on list page for submitting review.
Use of the popup,

1. When user clicks on write review on list page, it generates a popup with form to submit the review.
2. Here is my custom form for the popup, I want to add "rating box" in the form.
3. I tried adding default rating table of "rwd" `review/form.phtml` but it's not working.

Suggest solution to add rating input:

```
 <div class="p_content_list write_review">
       <h2>Write A Review</h2>
       <div class="close_box"><a href="#" class="p_close js__p_close" title="Close"></a></div>
       <span class="border-bottom"></span>
       <div class="col-main">
        <form id="review-form" action="" method="post">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
            <div class="fieldset wide">
                <div class="wide">
                    <div class="left-form">
                        <label for="billing:street1">Title</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="title" title="Title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="" /> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="rate">
                        <p>Click To Rate</p>
                        **I WANT CODE FOR RATING ON THIS TAG**
                     </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:street1">Review</label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea type="text" name="detail" id="review_field" class="input-text  required-entry" value="" title="Review"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Submit Review')) ?>" class="button color-border">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" title="Continue" class="button cancel">Cancel</button>
             </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>    
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot  this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try below code This might work for you.

```
<?php 
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);  
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view_list')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('review/product/view/list.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar You are always welcome

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala  do you have an Idea how to do this on magento 2.1?

Comment: @RonakChauhan same syntax just change block type as in magento 2 and change template as in magento 2

Comment: I want to show review form in custom page http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152353/magento-2-add-review-form-on-custom-page  

Pls help you have any idea

Comment: I have product object but not getting how would i call review block directly

Comment: @RonakChauhan update your code what you have tried, I haven't tried  this thing in magento 2 but may I get some idea what mistake you have done

Comment: i put my xml code , check it