# Magento 2 Add review form on custom page

Tags: magento-2.1, review, ratings

I have custom module page which has products on a slider.

When I click on slider product according to that product I want to show a **Review - Rating Form on custom page** which can be **filled once by customer who logged-In**.

Here is the page where I want to show **review form** :
[image]

When I click on test product review form should be visible on a block.

Below form should be visible according to Product :
[image]

**Updated code** (I tried this in my xml):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="<vendor>\Review\Block\Order\Products" name="thinkideas_review_products" template="<vendor>_Review::reviewproducts.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.order.test" as="reviews_testorder" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" >

                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form.test" as="review_form_order"/>
                    </block>
            </block>
    </referenceContainer>       
</body>
```

**Any suggestion would be appreciated**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to layout XML of your custom module :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submitReviewButton" xsi:type="string">.review .action.submit</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
            <block class="<vendor>\<module_name>\Block\Order\Products" name="review_products" template="<Vendor>_<Module>::reviewproducts.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Then append review phtml code to your phtml which you want to use as form.

Comment: can you please answer this question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220373/how-to-send-a-review-form-in-mail-after-buy-products-in-magento

Comment: you can use this as reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2

Comment: @RonakChauhan can you share your `review.phtml` file code? my requirement is similar to you.