# How to create a custom form for sending email with file attachment in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

**How to create a custom form for sending email in Magento 2**

**Fields are like**

- First name
- Last name
- Address
- City
- State
- Zip code
- Email
- Phone
- Product type: checkbox Option like (1) One (2) Two
- File upload
- comment

Comment: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/transactional-emails-in-magento-2/

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187855/pass-variable-and-output-in-custom-email-template/187862

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132391/how-to-send-mail-programmaticlly-in-magento2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Try below code in your controller**

> vendorname/modulename/controller/Index/index.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;


class Index extends Action
{
    private $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */

    protected $context;
    private $fileUploaderFactory;
    private $fileSystem;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Modia\Cform\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('upload_document');

        if ($filesData['name']) {
         $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'upload_document']);
         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
         $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
         $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('test-doc');
         $result = $uploader->save($path);
         $upload_document = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
         $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
         $fileName = $result['name'];
    } else {
         $upload_document = '';
         $filePath = '';
         $fileName = '';
    }

        $txt='<table>';

        if($post['fname']){         
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Client Name</strong>:'.$post['fname'].'</td></tr>';          
        }
        if($post['address']){           
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Address</strong>:'.$post['address'].'</td></tr>';            
        }
        if($post['city']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>City</strong>:'.$post['city'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['state']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>State/Province</strong>:'.$post['state'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['zipcode']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Zip Code</strong>:'.$post['zipcode'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['phone']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Phone</strong>:'.$post['phone'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['email']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Email</strong>:'.$post['email'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if(!empty($post['project_type'])){      
            $projecttypearray = implode(",",$post['project_type']);     
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Project Type</strong>:'.$projecttypearray.'</td></tr>';          
        }

        if($post['comment']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $txt.='</table>';
        //echo $txt;



        $customerName='Demo Form';
        $message=$txt;

        $userSubject= 'Demo From ';     
        $fromEmail= 'admin@gmail.com.com';
        $fromName = 'Test Demo Form';

         $templateVars = [
                    'store' => 1,
                    'customer_name' => $customerName,
                    'subject' => $userSubject,
                    'message'   => $message
                ];
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();


        $to = 'test@gmail.com';     

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(5, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)               
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('form');
    }

}
```

> vendorname/modulename/etc/di.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Vendorname\Modulename\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

> Vendorname/Modulename/Magento/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($file, $name)
    {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
 <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="url/cform/index/index">
        <div class="form-group">    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="">Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="fname" placeholder="first name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="lname" placeholder="last name">
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <textarea class="col-sm-12 form-control" rows="3" placeholder="" name="address"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <label for="">City</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">State/Province</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="">Zip Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label for="">Phone</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="phone" placeholder="">
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-2 phone-or">
                                <span>OR</span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" placeholder="">
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="">Project Type :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="" value="One1" name="project_type[]"> <span>Residential</span> 
                    </label> 
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="" value="One2" name="project_type[]"> <span>Commercial</span>
                    </label>        
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <input accept="image/*" name="upload_document" type="file" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="">Comment :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="3" name="comment" placeholder="additional information about your project"></textarea>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**Now call in cms page**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendorname_Modulename::test.phtml" }}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it's not working

Comment: This answer is very lacking in context and it has multiple errors in it, but I eventually debugged every error and filled in all the gaps to get it to work somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Cform" setup_version="2.2.0">
        
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/registration.php

```
<?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Vendor_Cform',
        __DIR__
    );
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="cform" frontName="cform">
            <module name="Vendor_Cform" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Cform\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        /**
         * Create table 'vendor_contect'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('vendor_contect')
        )->addColumn(
            'contect_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Contect Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Email Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'telephone',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Phone Number'
        )->addColumn(
            'comment',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'What’s on your mind?'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index")?>">
    <h1><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Form')) ?></h1>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field name">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" class="input-text" type="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" id="add" title="" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
        var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index") ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        $('#contact-form')[0].reset(); 
        return false;
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/Controller/Index/index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Cform\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;


class Index extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
        $data = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Cform\Model\Cform');
        $data->setData($post);
        $data->save();
        /* echo "hello";
        exit; */
        
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));
             
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/Model/Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Cform\Model;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }

}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/Model/ResourceModel/Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Cform\Model\ResourceModel;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $storeManager;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_contect', 'contect_id');
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Cform/Model/ResourceModel/Cform/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform;
 
use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
 
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
 
    protected $_idFieldName = \Vendor\Cform\Model\Cform::CONTECT_ID;
     
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Vendor\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }
 
}
```

CMS page Call

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Cform::form.phtml" }}
```

app/code/Vendor/Cform/view/frontend/layout/contactform_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\ContactForm\Block\Form" name="contactForm" template="Vendor_ContactForm::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is this linked to your other answer? I know in test.phtml, it refers to "cform" in the form action - I assume it's this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a simple html form and submit data to your controller.
2. Get all your post values in your controller and send mail using below function.

You can send mail using **Zend_Mail()** function.

```
// Get your post values
$firstname = "Dinesh";
$lastname = "Yadav";

// Send Mail functionality starts from here 
$from = "from_email_address@example.com";
$nameFrom = "From Name";
$to = "to_email_address@example.com";
$nameTo = "To Name";
$body = "
<div>
    <b>".$firstname."</b>
    <i>".$lastname."</i>
</div>";

$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Email Subject"); 
$email->setBodyHtml($body);     // use it to send html data
//$email->setBodyText($body);   // use it to send simple text data
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Contact is vendor and Us is module.Here i am posting my form data to my frontend controller Post.php

step 1: Create email_templates.xml in app/code/Contact/Us/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="send_email_email_template" label="Email Form" file="email_template.html" type="text" module="Contact_Us" area="frontend"/>
```

step 2: Create email_template.html in app/code/Contact/Us/view/frontend/email

```
<!--@subject xMage-support@-->
   <!--@vars {
     "var data.comment":"xMage-support",
     "var data.email":"support@xmagestore.com",
     "var data.name":"XMageStore"
    } @-->


  {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

  {{trans "Dear %name" name=$data.name}}
  {{trans "we received your request regarding %queryregarding" 
    queryregarding=$data.requestType}}

  {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Step 3: Create Post.php controller in app/code/Contact/Us/Controller/Post

```
<?php
namespace Contact\Us\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
 */
protected $inlineTranslation;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $_escaper;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

/**
 * Post user question
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$post) {
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try {
        $recipientMail = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('email');

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);

        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => 'xMageStore',
            'email' => 'support@xmagestore.com',
        ];

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($recipientMail)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('Thanks for contacting us. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.' . $e->getMessage())
        );
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    }
  }
}
```