# How to save attachment in database using custom form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, ajax

I have created a custom form on the frontend, and want to save data in the database as well display in the admin.

My Form:

```
<form id="career-form" name="career-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="rendered-form">
        <div class="form-group field-name">
            <label for="name" class="fb-text-label">Name<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-email">
            <label for="mail" class="fb-text-label">E-mail<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="enter your Email"id="mail" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" aria-required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-mobile">
            <label for="mobile" class="fb-text-label">Mobile Number<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="form-control" name="mobile" maxlength="10" id="mobile" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-applied">
            <label for="applied" class="fb-text-label">Applied For<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="applied" id="applied" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-intro">
            <label for="intro" class="fb-textarea-label">Short Introduction</label>
            <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="intro" rows="5" id="intro"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-resume">
            <label for="resume" class="fb-file-label">Upload Resume<span class="fb-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="resume" id="resume" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-apply">
            <?php /* ?><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="apply-success">Button</button><?php */ ?>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="submit comment" id="apply-success"/>
        </div>
        <span id="formLoader">&nbsp;</span>
        <span id="successmsg">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller Code:

```
<?php 
namespace Allin\Video\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Career extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

 public function execute()
    {
    $i=0;
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

         if(1)
        {

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
            $mediaPath=$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
            $media = $mediaPath . 'test-doc/';
            $file_name = rand() . $_FILES['resume']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['resume']['type'];
            $file_path = $media . $file_name;

//echo $file_name; die;
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $media . $file_name)) {
            echo $file_name;
        } else {
            echo "File was not uploaded";
        }   



            //echo 'testtttttttttttttt';
            $to = 'allin.vinodkumar@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Career Form';
            $name = $post['name'];
            //echo $name; die;
            $email = $post['email'];
            $phone = $post['mobile'];
            $applied = $post['applied'];
            $intro = $post['intro'];
            //$resume = $_FILES['resume']['name'];


            $message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\r\n" . "Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n". 'Post: ' . $applied. "\r\n" . 'Intro: ' . $intro;
            //echo $message; die;
            $headers = 'From:'. $email;
//echo $message; die;
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 


            $model = $objectManager->create('Allin\Resume\Model\Jobresume');
            $model->setData('name', $post['name']);
            $model->setData('email', $post['email']);
            $model->setData('phone', $post['mobile']);
            $model->setData('post', $post['applied']);
            $model->setData('intro', $post['intro']);
            $model->setData('format', $post['type']);
            $model->save();

             echo 'Thanks for applying the Job. We will contact you asap.';

        }

    }
}
```

Ajax Code to call Controller:

```
<script>
//========================Comment Form======================================//
require(['jquery'], function() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    jQuery( "#apply-success" ).click(function() {
        if(1){
        var data = jQuery('#career-form').serialize();
        //alert(data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo $this->getUrl().'video/index/career';?>",
            type:'POST',
            data: data,
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                 jQuery("#formLoader").html("<img src='http://www.example.com/pub/media/zipcode/loading.gif'/>");
                 jQuery("#formLoader").show();
            },
                success: function(response)
            {   
                jQuery("#formLoader").hide();
                jQuery("#successmsg").html(response);
                jQuery("#successmsg").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                jQuery("#career-form")[0].reset();


            }
        });
        }else{ return false; }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

I am unable to get image in the controller and save in the database.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2 try this