# Secondary contact form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, contact-form

how I can create a secondary contact form with mangento2x, I want to customize a contact form for clients feedback, I saw a lot of extensions that do what I want but they are not free, is there an easy way to be able to do it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2 try this link like custom from and send email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom form for sending email with file Attachment in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

**Step-1:** go to "app" from root directory of Magento 2 and create new directory code. Then create two more directories in app/code, Namespace and Module Name. The final directory will look like this: **app/code/Demo/Contact**

**Step-2:** create **registration.php** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_Contact',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-3:** create **module.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_Contact" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-4:** create **di.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Demo\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

**Step-5:** create **email_templates.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Demo_Contact" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

**Step-6:** create **Post.php** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/Controller/Index** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Contact\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);
            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['custom_field_1']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['custom_field_2']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }


            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('contact_us');
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->set('contact_us', $post);
            $this->_redirect('contact/index');
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }
}
```

**Step-7:** create **contact_index_index.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/view/frontend/layout** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Demo_Contact::form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step-8:** create **form.phtml** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/view/frontend/templates** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Us') ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.') ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field custom_field_1 required">
            <label class="label" for="custom_field_1"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Field 1') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="custom_field_1" id="custom_field_1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Field 1') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('custom_field_1') ?: "") ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field custom_field_2 required">
            <label class="label" for="custom_field_2"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Field 2') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="custom_field_2" id="custom_field_2" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Field 2') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('custom_field_2') ?: "") ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Step-9:** create **submitted_form.html** file in **app/code/Demo/Contact/view/adminhtml/email** and paste below code into the file:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Comment Form"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.comment":"Comment",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.username":"Sender Name",
"var data.post_title":"Post Title"
"var data.custom_field_1":"Custom Field 1"
"var data.custom_field_2":"Custom Field 2"
} @-->

{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.username}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Post Title: %post_title" post_title=$data.post_title}}
{{trans "Custom Field 1: %custom_field_1" custom_field_1=$data.custom_field_1}}
{{trans "Custom Field 2: %custom_field_2" custom_field_2=$data.custom_field_2}}

{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

Comment: Hello Nilesh, i followed the instruction but i have a question for Step-8: create contact_index_index.xml  is that right .xml or should be .php and when i'm done how i can introduce the contact form to CMS page

Comment: Kindly review, I have updated my answer