# Contact form does not send email

Tags: magento2

When I am sending the form detail It work.but do not receive the Email.I set the email like sale@example.uk when I set it like sale@example.com it work. I think problem is .uk and .com domain name.can any one tell me how to solve .

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2 try this link

Comment: i want to change the validation of default file

Answer (score 0):

Now first check simple mail send or not

```
<?php
$to = "you@youraddress.com";
$subject = "Test email";
$message = "This is a test email.";
$from = "from@fromaddress.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo("Your message has been sent successfully");
    } else {
    echo("Sorry, your message could not be sent");
}
?>
```

Comment: which default file  I  use this code

Comment: and my email address from@fromaddress.uk

Comment: root folder create php file and check it.