# Not able to send email from custom module

Tags: magento2, email

How to debug following code.

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate)
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => 'adminhtml',
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($emailSender)
                ->addTo($emailRecipient)
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();
```

It is getting failed without any error or exception message.

Comment: Have you tried to debug with some sort of debugger e.g `xdebug`? Do you also have a `SMTP` server?

Comment: Emails are working fine.

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Basics of debugging with XDEBUG: https://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/

Comment: Yes, I am using xdebug. But didn't find anything unusual.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with class `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/SenderResolver.php`

```
public function resolve($sender, $scopeId = null)
    {
        $result = [];

        if (!is_array($sender)) {
            $result['name'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/name',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
            $result['email'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/email',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
        } else {
            $result = $sender;
        }

        if (!isset($result['name']) || !isset($result['email'])) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(__('Invalid sender data'));
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

I am passing the string in `setFrom` which is creating the problem. 
Fixed it by passing the array.

Changed

```
setFrom($emailSender)
```

to

```
setFrom(['email'=> $emailSender, 'name'=> $senderName])
```