# Magento2.2 Custom form not sending data via email

Tags: magento2.2, contact-form, post-data

I have followed [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201816/65994) about creating a form that sends data to a specific email. The module works, but the form isn't sending data to the given email.

For simplicity I am going to paste the code given in the above post and write my comments afterwards

---

> vendorname/modulename/controller/Index/index.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;


class Index extends Action
{
    private $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */

    protected $context;
    private $fileUploaderFactory;
    private $fileSystem;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Modia\Cform\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('upload_document');

        if ($filesData['name']) {
         $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'upload_document']);
         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
         $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
         $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('test-doc');
         $result = $uploader->save($path);
         $upload_document = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
         $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
         $fileName = $result['name'];
    } else {
         $upload_document = '';
         $filePath = '';
         $fileName = '';
    }

        $txt='<table>';

        if($post['fname']){         
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Client Name</strong>:'.$post['fname'].'</td></tr>';          
        }
        if($post['address']){           
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Address</strong>:'.$post['address'].'</td></tr>';            
        }
        if($post['city']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>City</strong>:'.$post['city'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['state']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>State/Province</strong>:'.$post['state'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['zipcode']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Zip Code</strong>:'.$post['zipcode'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['phone']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Phone</strong>:'.$post['phone'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['email']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Email</strong>:'.$post['email'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if(!empty($post['project_type'])){      
            $projecttypearray = implode(",",$post['project_type']);     
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Project Type</strong>:'.$projecttypearray.'</td></tr>';          
        }

        if($post['comment']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $txt.='</table>';
        //echo $txt;



        $customerName='Demo Form';
        $message=$txt;

        $userSubject= 'Demo From ';     
        $fromEmail= 'admin@gmail.com.com';
        $fromName = 'Test Demo Form';

         $templateVars = [
                    'store' => 1,
                    'customer_name' => $customerName,
                    'subject' => $userSubject,
                    'message'   => $message
                ];
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();


        $to = 'test@gmail.com';     

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(5, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)               
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('form');
    }

}
```

> vendorname/modulename/etc/di.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Vendorname\Modulename\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

> Vendorname/Modulename/Magento/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($file, $name)
    {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
 <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="url/cform/index/index">
        <div class="form-group">    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="">Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="fname" placeholder="first name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="lname" placeholder="last name">
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <textarea class="col-sm-12 form-control" rows="3" placeholder="" name="address"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <label for="">City</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">State/Province</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="">Zip Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" id="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label for="">Phone</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="phone" placeholder="">
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-2 phone-or">
                                <span>OR</span>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" placeholder="">
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="">Project Type :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="" value="One1" name="project_type[]"> <span>Residential</span> 
                    </label> 
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="" value="One2" name="project_type[]"> <span>Commercial</span>
                    </label>        
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <input accept="image/*" name="upload_document" type="file" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="">Comment :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="3" name="comment" placeholder="additional information about your project"></textarea>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**Now call in cms page**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendorname_Modulename::test.phtml" }}
```

---

I think the error resides in the `action` field of the template file. I replaced `vendorname/modulename` with my own in all the files, but the `action` url should point to the controller file, right?

So it should be something like `vendorname/modulename/index/index` or `modulename/index/index` , right? Well neither of the above work, so I would love any kind of help.

PS. 
I also suspect the way I am using the `cms-code` for the `block`. Maybe there should be a mention of a different `url`? I don't know, I have been fighting with this for a few days now.

Thank you for you time!

Comment: Does your form pass proper data into controller?

Comment: I don't know. How could I test that?

Comment: You need to debug that things first, then check further things.

Comment: Thank you, will try. Any help would be certainly welcome

Answer (score 1):

A complete wild shot but could you try the following?

```
action="<?php echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>"
```

or

```
action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>"
```

Comment: Overall my module doesn't work. However with `getFormActionUrl()` the form submits. And by submits I mean that after you press submit it returns to the same page (instead of an error page with the before action url). However no email gets send, and I don't know how to troubleshoot the whole module.