# How to add contact us form and functionality programmatically in frontend magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Actually, I want to add contact us form  and functionality
programmatically in Magento 2 custom theme in frontend.

Comment: For `Admin` or` Frontend` ?

Comment: refere below link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

In Homepage or any block or cms page just add below shortcode for getting contact us form.

> {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm"
>   template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}

Comment: custom contact us form functionality not this one

Comment: please refer below link for creating custom form in front end,

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2