# Implementation of sending selected items along with feedback form

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, knockoutjs, contact-form

Tell me how to implement the functionality of such a sample. On a separate page there is a form with any fields 2 or more and a submit button. I will use this example to implement. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201816/83080

But here is the difficulty. There are also elements with checkboxes on the page, they need to be selected and sent along with the form by 2 email. Customer and Administrator.

Tell me how to implement this or Mb someone was see examples of such an implementation, at least partial, I will be grateful for any help

[image]

Comment: You need to send mail to customer and administration with given field name, email and selected element right??

Comment: @NareshRupareliya yes

Comment: Code posted. can u please check and let me know it's working for you or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download module from [here](https://github.com/nareshrupareliya/Form-With-Mail/blob/master/Beckman.zip) and install it.

I have created example module i.e **Warranty** and there is a form with **name, email and elements**

Elements contain 5 options : Element A, Element B, Element C, Element D, Element E(you can set option as per your requirement)

please type in url : yoursitepath/warranty/registration/index to open below form(you can change this path by URL Rewrite)

[image]

You need to set some back-end configuration :

Go to **Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> General >> Contacts**

- **Send Emails To** = admin@gmail.com(here you can set your admin mail where your administrator can get mail)
- **Email Sender** = General Contact(Here you can set Sender Email Identity that means customer and admin will get mail from this mail id)

[image]

Getting mail looks like :

[image]

**Note :**

- Install module
- You can change form name and maessages title as per your module and as per your requirement. I have set dummy titles in this example.
- Make sure your mail sending functionality should be configured

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Naresh, sorry for the long answer, thanks for the example, it is very useful, I can’t test it now, but I wonder if the checkboxes are part of the form?
This is a small condition by which I separately looked for a solution. I will have 3 sliders in which there will be elements with checkboxes, this will be implemented by separate cms blocks. Is it possible to somehow get data from checkboxes that are not part of the form?

Comment: You need to call all the blocks inside one single form after that you can get value

Comment: Is this the right way to call 4 sliders in a form?

Comment: Yes it's right way to call 4 sliders in a single form.